# Is there a way to enable Hotspot when connected to a specific Bluetooth source?

Tags: bluetooth, wifi-hotspot, 8.0-oreo

I'd like to enable hotspot when my phone connects to the bluetooth in my car (basically turn it on when I start my car).

It would be nice if there was a way to do this in Android 8.0 (Pixel XL), but i'll assume that isn't possible.

Couldn't find a way to do it in IFTTT. Is there another third party app that will let me do this?

I'm not against coding my own script to do this, but I get the feeling that attempting this on a non-rooted device will be quite difficult (if not impossible).

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Tasker](http://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to accomplish this

**Profile (or Trigger)**

Create a Profile which allows triggering of the Tasker upon bluetooth connection:

- Go to Profiles Tab and click the "+"
- State ➡  Net ➡ BT Connected [Name : *Name of your car BT*, Address: *MAC of your Car BT*)
- Tap back to exit from this window

**Task**

You will notice as soon exit, you will be prompted to link this to a Task

- Scroll all the way up the Task list select "New Task + "
- You can name this Task *AutoTethering* or anything or leave optionally as anonymous task.
- Click "+" to add new Action
- Net ➡ WiFi Tether (Set On)

*Explanation: When Tasker detects the device is connected to another device(car) via bluetooth, it will run a task that activates wi-fi tether.*

This should work cheers.

Comment: Will this automatically turn it off when the bluetooth disconnects, or is that a new task?

Comment: Yes. When a task no longer matches the state, tasker returns the value to default (i.e disables tether) but in any case, you could create an exit task specifically for that.